# 3d scatter plot wiht 3-dimension list

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
print(grid)

xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, zmin, zmax = 0, x, 0, y, 0, z  
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (6, 6)  
fig = plt.figure()  
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

plt.plot(grid)
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()

ax.scatter(x,y,z)
```

I want to plot 3D scatter graph. but scatter() always has to use x,y,z data frame. There is only a 3-dimension list data that I have. I want 3d scatter plot with 3-dimension list as picture below.

[image]

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...
[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: Where exactly are you facing problem? Also, the picture seems to be a boolean matrix, do you intend to use the matrix indices as coordinates for your scatter plot?

Comment: Did you look through the [Matplotlib gallery](https://matplotlib.org/gallery#mplot3d) to see if there was anything that would work for you or that you could adapt to your circumstance?

Comment: thank you for your advice. check the gallery first and then if it couldn't work, I ask again.